# gdb reverse stepping - not supported in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

```
(gdb) reverse-step
Target child does not support this command.
```

This is in Linux 2.6.18

Does the kernel not support it?  Is there a special gcc arg I need?

```
 gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
```

Comment: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord

Comment: That's just.. unbelievable. Very nice feature! But isn't it unbearably slow?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - hmm...well...that feature is kind of useless...was hoping it would help me debug situations where a pointer gets turned into an absurd value.  Wanted to step back from a crash and work forward to see how it had happened.  The record command can't even handle the first few system calls my program makes.  Oh well.  Did verify that it works if I don't try to "continue".  If you made that an answer you could whore some points...

Comment: @CrazyEddie The reverse debugging feature is very useful, and it can be used for exactly the scenario you describe. You just need an up-to-date `gdb`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but it appears that maybe you forgot to enable gdb recording.

```
(gdb) record
(gdb) continue
(gdb) reverse-continue
Continuing.
```

For example, this worked for me

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffe673b5638) at ...
7     int lol = 0xbeefface;
(gdb) record
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program stopped.
0x00007f710c188746 in __GI__exit ...
(gdb) reverse-continue
Continuing.
...
No more reverse-execution history.
main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffe673b5638) at ...
7     int lol = 0xbeefface;
```

I was able to reproduce your issue with

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffeb7945198) at main.c:7
7     int lol = 0xbeefface;
(gdb) b _exit
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7fc62dbb8710: file ...
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __GI__exit ...
(gdb) reverse-continue
Target native does not support this command.
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is in Linux 2.6.18
>
> Does the kernel not support it?

The kernel has *nothing* to do with it. What version of *gdb* are you using?

Given that your GCC dates from 2008, and that GDB added support for reverse execution in version 7.0, released in 2009, I am guessing your GDB is just *too damn old*.